# Method, which return list of instance methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reflection

I'm stuck with two things. This is structure of my file.

```
class Person
  #...
  def self.class_name (object)
     object.class.name
  end
end

class Worker < Person
  #... 
end

class Client < Person
  #...
end

c = Client.new("1", "2", "3", "4")
Person.class_name(c)
```

I would like to create method, where as argument i can put some object and it will detect, what class is it and return me list of all instance methods, which don't require any argument. Later i need to somehow use all these methods.

I have found this:

```
testObject.class.name 
# returns name of class as a string

Class.instance_methods(false)
# returns list of instance method, which were defined in Class
```

First problem, is that i don't understand why i can't make something like

```
className = testObject.class.name 
className.instance_methods(false)
```

I suppose, that's because i got just class name, as a sting, not a real reference to the class. I have even created simple class_name method, which returns correct name of class, but i'm wondering how i can use `instance_methods(false)`, once i have this name. Also is there some option to choose only methods, which don't require any argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to create method, where as argument i can put some object
>   and it will detect, what class is it and return me list of all
>   instance methods

```
class Person
  def self.instance_methods(object)
    object.class.instance_methods(false)
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
c = Client.new("1", "2", "3", "4")
Person.instance_methods(c)
#=> returns an array of all instance methods defined in Client class
```

> Also is there some option to choose only methods, which don't require
>   any argument?

Yes, you have to check [`method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-method)'s [`arity`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Method.html#method-i-arity) and select those, which has zero:

```
class Person
  def self.instance_methods_with_arity_zero(object)
    object.class.instance_methods(false).map do |method|
      object.method(method).arity.zero?
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
c = Client.new("1", "2", "3", "4")
Person.instance_methods_with_arity_zero(c)
#=> returns an array of instance methods which take no arguments defined in Client class
```

The latter method can be shortened to use the first defined method:

```
def self.instance_methods_with_arity_zero(object)
  # we are using the previously defined instance_methods method
  instance_methods(object).map { |method| object.method(method).arity.zero? }
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're probably the fastest person I've ever seen on any forum :D.

Comment: @DanZawadzki you're welcome! It is just a coincidence, that I've noticed your question right after you created it :D

Comment: Everything works fine, but im thinking now how to "activate" these methods. Also can you advice me some good resource of information about ror? At this moment i'm basing on http://ruby-doc.org. Is there something else i can use?

Comment: @DanZawadzki what do you mean by "activating"? ruby-doc.org is very good source! If you're open to books recommendations - `Metaprogramming Ruby 2` is definitely something you should read.

Comment: Sorry, it's a wrong word. I mean, at this moment it returns parameterless methods `=> [:to_s, :raise_sallary]`, but i'm thinking how to use these on the object which was given to the `instance_methods_with_arity_zero` as a parameter. Ah, and thanks for recommendation. I used to write a little bit in java, but at this moment im thinking to focuss more on ruby, because its way more interesting, then i was thinkng

Comment: @DanZawadzki So you want to call returned methods on the object? You can use [`public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-public_send) method - it takes a symbol as parameter and calls this method on the receiver: `object.public_send(:to_s)`. There is also a [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-send) method which differs in a way, that it does not care on the method's visibility level and will call private methods as well, whereas `public_send` will throw an exception if you try to call private method with it.

Comment: Oh, exactly. Thanks a lot! "call" this word i was searching for :D. `object.public_send(:to_s)` and this method i was searching for :D. You are like walking ror documentation :D!

Comment: @DanZawadzki heh :) Good luck learning! Will be glad to help if I can :)

Comment: Methods which have only a splat parameter, only optional parameters with default arguments, only optional keyword parameters with default arguments, or any combination thereof, also don't require any argument!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to turn it into a string:

```
klass = testObject.class
methods = klass.instance_methods(false)
```

If you have to deal with a string representation of the class name, then turn it back into a class first:

```
klass = "String".constantize
string_methods = klass.instance_methods(false)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didnt understand, that adding `.name` transform it to the string. I will remember for sure!